# EntityFrameworkCore - DbFirst - Map two tables with same structure to single object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, scaffolding, ef-database-first

I'm using EntityFrameworkCore6 with database-first approach in my C# project.

I have two tables with same structure (one for current status, one for history status); let's simplify with:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[current_status](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[datetime] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
[status] [int] NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[history_status](
[id] [int] NOT NULL,
[datetime] [datetime2](0) NOT NULL,
[status] [int] NOT NULL)
```

on current status table update operations are performed, while on history status insert operations are performed.

Right now I have done scaffolding, getting two separate objects/dtos and two separate dbsets. Everytime I need to perform the update/insert operations on the two tables, I need to do some object mapping (since they are different, even having identical fields).

I was wondering if there is some way (during scaffolding or inside OnModelCreating) for getting only one object/dto and two separate dbset both built on that single object/dto. I've tried looking on the web but I was unable to find the answer to my situation.

Here below the scaffolded context:

```
    public partial class My_Context : DbContext
{
    public My_Context()
    {
    }

    public My_Context(DbContextOptions<My_Context> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CurrentStatus> CurrentStatuses { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual DbSet<HistoryStatus> HistoryStatuses { get; set; } = null!;
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            //connection string hidden
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<CurrentStatus>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.ToTable("current_status", "dbo");

            entity.Property(e => e.Datetime)
                .HasPrecision(0)
                .HasColumnName("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("status");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryStatus>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.ToTable("history_status", "dbo");

            entity.Property(e => e.Datetime)
                .HasPrecision(0)
                .HasColumnName("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("id");

            entity.Property(e => e.Status).HasColumnName("status");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, if insert/update is your main problem you may call a stored procedure to populate the tables. Also you can create a generic function to perform this.

Comment: It sis possible. Can you please share your scaffolded DBContext code here?

Comment: @MiladSoghrati yes, give just few minutes to update the question

Comment: After looking at your code I realized I misunderstood your problem.
EF Core only supports having one mapping in the model for each entity type so you cannot map one entity to two tables like that. There are tricks in case you don't want to insert/update but not exactly what you are looking for. You can also use inheritance and derive one object from the other.